# Bad file descriptor error

Tags: python, file

If I try executing the following code

```
f = file('test','rb')
fout = file('test.out','wb')

for i in range(10):
    a = f.read(1)
    fout.write(a)

f.close()
f = fout
f.seek(4)

print f.read(4)
```

Where `'test'` is any arbitrary file, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testbad.py", line 12, in <module>
    print f.read(4)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

If however, I change just the fout line to use a temporary file:

```
import tempfile

f = file('test','rb')
fout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

for i in range(10):
    a = f.read(1)
    fout.write(a)

f.close()
f = fout
f.seek(4)

print f.read(4)
```

There are no errors. Does anyone know why this is? I would have expected the first case to work, but I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you've only opened the file `fout` for writing, not reading. To open for both use

```
fout = file('test.out','r+b')
```

Comment: I don't know if/when things changed but according to the current docs, and my personal experience, you now need to use 'r+' or 'r+b' to open a file for both reading and writing https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @JonoCoetzee It seems that both work equivalently, but I've edited it to be better aligned with the docs. Thanks.