# How to convert an array to a data file?

Tags: python, arrays

Using this

```
with open("./data.dat") as file:
    data = [map(float, ln.split()) for ln in file]
```

one can convert a data file to an array. How I can do the opposite?

Specifically, I want to convert something like:

> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

to a data.dat file with the following content:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: I don't think one should call this "converting".

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("./data.data", 'w') as file:
    for line in data:
        file.write(' '.join([str(d) for d in line]) + '\n')
```

Comment: list comprehension in unnecessary, you can just do `' '.join(str(d) for d in data)`

Comment: string joins are actually faster with a list comprehension than a generator. something about looping over the list twice

Comment: That looks to be correct.  How odd.

Comment: Did anybody actually test the above answer?

Comment: It doesn't work for me at the first try.

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan It looks like you've changed your question since I answered it. I'll update my answer this time, but it's important to provide the right information from the beginning so nobody wastes any time.

Comment: @mhlester, You are absolutely right but I just found my question can be more specific. I wasn't aware of that fact at that time. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It does not work for me, nope!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_plot.py", line 23, in <module>
    file.write(' '.join([str(d) for d in line]) + '\n')
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: [are you sure you opened the file for writing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368967/bad-file-descriptor-error)